# How can iOS 16 BLE scan frequency in background speed up again

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are developed an App which started some interaction with our BLE device by simply presenting a iPhone. Until now we `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:` with background mode. It scanned with a polling frequency of ~1,5secs. But since iOS 16 this polling frequency changed to 10-15secs, which rendered our application virtually useless since the user had to wait up to 15secs until it gets a response.

Comment: Hmmm... we use that call (using Xamarin), and we don't see this.  What does "Background mode" mean here?

Comment: "Background mode" means that the app continues scanning even if another App or the lock screen is active.
@bobwki: What is the BLE scanfrequency of your App if another App is running on a iOS 16 device?